# How do I sort a file that has a very long list of items?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a text file that has a very long list of items. So I want to sort them alphabetically but I do not want to load all the file into the memory (RAM).

I tried loading all the contents of the file to an array and sort them just like I do normally. But the system complains that there are no much memory!!

Thanks,
Mohammad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to read up on [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). The basic approach is to use some sort of divide-and-conquer routine like [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort), where you read and sort a portion of the file, then read and sort another portion of the file, etc. and when you get to the end you merge the sorted portions together.

Comment: You can view here a nice course about external sorting. http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-978892635109400080#

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) (Standard Template Library for Extra Large Data Sets) helps.

STXXL offers [external sorting](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/stxxl/tags/1.2.1/group__stlalgo.html#g6037597e33eafc47a6a90cb971a11c82) amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hold the whole file in memory. If this is a task you don't have to do very often, you can write an application that sorts it very slow. Something like this (pseudo):

```
vector<int> linesProcessed;
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
   if (linesProcessed contains i) continue;
   string alphabeticalFirstLine;
   int lineIndex;
   foreach line in oldFile
   {
       if (line is before alphabeticalFirstLine)
       {
            alphabeticalFirstLine = line;
            lineIndex = i;
       }
   }
   write alphabeticalFirstLine to newFile;
   vector.add(lineIndex);
}
clear vector;
delete oldFile;
rename newFile to oldFile;
```

Comment: That's called selection sort (almost), not the best idea.

Comment: @unbeli: I know it is almost selection sort. Selection Sort searches also for the biggest value. But I wrote, "if this is a task you don't have to do very often, ..."

Comment: Even if one doesn't do it very often, why should she implement weak algorithm when there is a simple stronger one?

Comment: @unbeli: I didn't know about the External Sorting. So I posted a suggestion. That is the reason why I'm a user on Stack Overflow: help people and learn programming, get insight. I just wanted to help him...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some unix-like OS you can use sort command. It will take care about memory consumption.
For an example something like "cat large_file | sort" will do the job.

Or you can write your own / use external sorting from the library. Tell us  what language are you using and maybe someone will tell you exact library to use.